# is it possible to shorten this code? if string is null or has specific value at the beginning

Tags: c#

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1))
{
    if (s1[0] == 'a')
        s1 = s1.Remove(0, 1);
    else
        s1 = s1.Insert(0, "b");
}
else
    s1 = s1.Insert(0, "b");
```

<s>I want it to insert a letter "b" at the beginning of string s1 if s1 is null or s1 has a letter "a" at the beginning</s> I want it to insert a letter "b" at the beginning of string s1 if s1 is empty or doesn't have "a" at the beginning and remove the first letter if it has "a" at the beginning but if I use || in the first if statement, I'll get System.IndexOutOfRangeException when s1 is <s>null</s> empty. Is there any way to shorten this?

edit:
I completely messed the question up.

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but if s1 is null your else clause will fail ... because s1 is null.

Comment: You cannot insert a char into a null string.

Comment: Use `Try...Catch ` blocks to catch null strings and  `Trim` for empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
s1 = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) || s1[0] != 'a') ? s1.Insert(0, "b") : s1.Remove(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to do:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1))
            {
                if (s1.StartsWith("a"))
                {
                    s1 = "b" + s1.Substring(1);
                }                
            }
else
   s1 = "b";
```